# Monero mining set-up with GPU 8*NP106

Tags: mining, mining-hardware, mining-pool-setup

I have 8 GPUs of the model NP106 and I have been trying to use them for a monero rig. Is there any way I can use ccminer or claymore even though they are not GTX or AMD build. Would appreciate your view on how to go about with it.  Thanks, guys!

Answer (score 1):

It is my understanding that the NVidia P106 (if this is what you mean) are GTX without the display port. If I am correct, you should be able to use any NVidia compatible mining application based on your OS. `CCMINER` should do admirably.

Feel free to give a test on my Monero Pool and if I'm around I'll try and help via the chatbox.

**Gulf Coast Mining**
https://mon.gulfcoastmining.com

Answer (score 1):

CCMINER should work with NP106 models. The only difference is the I/O port is disabled. Have you tested it with CCMINER yet? What errors have you ran into?